# Error:A local variable named 'Model' cannot be declared in this scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I m returing a List to the View. So The Model is IEnumerable. It works fine in foreach loop to get the employees. But when I use this Model inside the loop it give me the error:

> A local variable named 'Model' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'Model', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.

Inside the loop when I use other name other than Model it works fine.

View
@model IEnumerable

```
@foreach (tbEmployee emp in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(Model => emp.empID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(Model  => emp.empName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(Model  => emp.empAge)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(Model  => emp.empStatus)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Employee")
                @Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update", "Employee")
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Employee")
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

But When I write like, it works fine

```
 @foreach (tbEmployee emp in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => emp.empID) //where this x get data from
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => emp.empName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => emp.empAge)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => emp.empStatus)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Employee")
                @Html.ActionLink("Update", "Update", "Employee")
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Employee")
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: You cant use `Model` in the lambda like that, the error message makes it clear.  `Model` already exists, so when you use `Model` in the lambda you are effectively creating another variable with the same name.  So just use `x` or anything else that isnt already taken.  To test, look at the output, its what you want right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a variable scope error (CS0136) in a Html.HiddenFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793537/why-do-i-get-a-variable-scope-error-cs0136-in-a-html-hiddenfor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, this error message has been removed in more recent versions of C#; the design team decided that it created more confusion than prevented errors.

The issue is that the name `Model` is here used to mean two things: whatever property or variable is used as the collection of the `foreach`, and as a formal parameter of a lambda.  Moreover, the two usages **overlap**. That is, the `Model` that is used in the `foreach` is *directly outside* the usages of `Model` as a formal inside the `foreach`.  Basically the compiler here is saying "you are creating a situation where you're possibly using the same name to mean two completely different things right next to each other" and that is a very confusing and bug prone situation to be in.

(Having two lambdas *beside* each other with the same names for the formal parameters is not illegal because they do not *overlap*. If one lambda was in another, that would give a similar error.)

This error message is well-intentioned but regrettably, the compiler does a poor job of explaining the problem to the user.  I did some work to improve that error message in... 2011 maybe? Or thereabouts.  But the improvements were marginal at best.

As you've discovered, the correct fix is **stop using the same name to mean two completely different things in the same scope**.